# Facebook API Post as User Fails if user is Page adming

Tags: facebook, api

I have tried just about everything at this point, but I cannot get a like or a comment to show up as my user, if I am logged in as the admin of a page. My app allows people to manage their pages, but even if I pass my user's access token back instead of my page's access token, it still performs the action as though it were the page. This is also true of the Graph API explorer. I've logged into Facebook, flipped over to posting as user, then ran the graph API on the post in question, generating a fresh access token from there and the post STILL showed up as the page! Is this broken? Should I submit this bug to FB?

Yes I have all the required permissions, yes I'm verifying that I'm using the user access token and not the page access token... the Facebook API returns true every time, however, even through the Graph API explorer and not through my app.

Comment: Turns out this is a known Facbeook bug, 

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/408406055876958....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/408406055876958

This is a known facebook bug, opened in July, with no timetable for fixing it.